# Why are my SharePoint 2010 List Control Items greyed out?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, permissions

All of a sudden I can no longer edit or view list items using the items tab.  I have full control of the site and I also added myself as a SCA.  I verified my permissions in Library permissions.  Item-Level Permissions are Read Access: Real All Items; Create and Edit access: create and edit all items.  Appears to be an issue with all lists and library.  Also, all controls on the list tab are grayed out until I deselect the item and reselect.  Could there be an issue with a recent SharePoint patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This issue exists in the recent sharepoint 2010 patch.

A fix for this issue was released by Microsoft on 27 April 2020.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484386/april-27-2020-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2010-kb4484386

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this make sure – that particular user has at least **READ** access to the **Master Page Gallery** library – you will find this from the **site settings** page -> **Web Designer Galleries** section (to get this option listed, you need to activate the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrusture feature**).